# Как вывести массив структур через fread(). 1 код для ввода структуры, а во втором я не могу вывести массив структур, пользуясь fread()

Tags: c++, c

1 код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
FILE *fd;
char name[10];
gets(name);
fd=fopen(name, "w");
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};
A mass[100];
int i;
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    scanf("%s%s%s", &mass[i].a, &mass[i].b, &mass[i].c);
}
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    fwrite(&mass[i], sizeof(mass[i]),1,fd );
}
fseek(fd,0, SEEK_END);
cout<<ftell(fd)<<endl;
system("pause");
fclose(fd);
}
```

2 Код

```
_______________________
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
FILE *fd;
char name[10];
int num_mass, num_fd, num, *p;
gets(name);
fd=fopen(name, "r");
fseek(fd,0, SEEK_END);
num_fd=ftell(fd);
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
cout<<num_fd<<endl;

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};
num_mass=sizeof(A);
cout<<num_mass<<endl;
num=num_fd/num_mass;
cout<<num<<endl;
A *mass=new A[num];
int i;
fread(&mass, sizeof(mass),1, fd);
printf("%d\t%d\t%s\n", mass[i].a,mass[i].b,mass[i].c );
fseek(fd,0, SEEK_END);
cout<<ftell(fd)<<endl;
system("pause");
fclose(fd);
}
```

Comment: Как следует из названия, функция `fread` предназначена исключительно для чтения.

Comment: извиняюсь, вопрос я некорректно поставил, правильно :как вывести структуру из файла,

Comment: переменной `int i;` не задали значение - будет рандомный эффект. Про *не можете* - расскажите подробнее.

Comment: Я понимаю, что делает первый код, вводит массив структур, А во втором я пытаюсь считать массив структур с помощью fread() и вывести консоль, у меня прекращает работу консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Файл нужно открывать для чтения и записи в бинарном режиме. Цикл можно не использовать - функции принимают количество элементов для записи/считывания

```
fd=fopen(name, "wb");
fwrite(mass, sizeof(mass[0]), num, fd);

fd=fopen(name, "rb");
fread(mass, sizeof(mass[0]), num, fd);
```

И зачем 2 отдельных программы?

Comment: две программы лишь для моего удобства

Comment: я исправил, но консоль все равно вылетает во второй программе

Comment: я еще немного свой код исправил и помогло, спасибо

Comment: Вылетает из-за неинициализированной переменной `int i; printf("%d\t%d\t%s\n", mass[i].a,mass[i].b,mass[i].c );` Когда вы обращаетесь к массиву по неизвестному индексу, получается выход за пределы массива.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тестовая программа - файловый ввод/вывод работает.
Значит у вас где-то ещё ошибка. С ручным вводом заранее никогда не скажешь.
Пробуйте в отладочном режиме.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

int main()
{
  FILE *fd;
  char* name = "f001.bin";
  int size = 3;
  A mass[size] = {
      { 1, 2, 'a'},
      { 3, 4, 'b'},
      { 5, 6, 'c'}
  };
  
  A mass1[size];
  
  fd=fopen(name, "wb");
  fwrite(mass, sizeof(mass[0]), size, fd);
  fclose(fd);
  
  fd=fopen(name, "rb");
  fread(mass1, sizeof(mass1[0]), size, fd);
  fclose(fd);
  
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
      cout<< mass1[i].a << " " << mass1[i].b << " " << mass1[i].c << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Я подправил программу, спасибо, помогли